# I [paused] a question and don't know how to "fix" it. What's good etiquette in this situation?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/what-is-the-proper-role-of-foundations-in-rigorous-mathematics-paused), but later felt that the question was imprecise and needed revision. So, I labelled it [paused] and wrote the following message at the top of the page.

> This question needs a major rewrite. Please regard it as 'paused' and inactive until I find the time to clarify the issues of concern. Thank you.

There's a few problems, though.

- A major rewrite could make the existing answers obsolete.
- Its still not clear to me what the "meat" of the question ought to be, and therefore:
- I don't currently - indeed, I may *never* - know how to rewrite the question.
- If I remove the aforementioned message, and delete the word [paused] from the title, the question will jump to the top of the mainpage and may thereby generate more answers, which I would feel bad about since after all I'm not happy with the question, and what right do I have to request people spend their time and effort answering something that I regard to be a bad question?

What's good etiquette in this situation?